# Run a single hardhat test

Tags: javascript, testing, hardhat, mocha

I have a test file in hardhat like so:

```js
const { expect } = require("chai");

describe("contract tests", function () {
  it("does function one", async function () {
    expect(await someContract.someFunc()).to.equal(something);
  });
  it("does function two", async function () {
    expect(await someContract.someOtherFunction()).to.equal(somethingOtherThing);
  });
});
```

How can I test just one of the `its` at a time?

In [mocha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10832031/how-to-run-a-single-test-with-mocha) you can run a single test with the `--grep` command. Is there something similar for hardhat?

Something like:

```sh
npx hardhat test --grep "does function one"
```

or

```sh
npx hardhat test --grep "does function two"
```

Comment: Woah! The famous Patrick Collins is asking questions on Stack Overflow?

I guess it's a good reminder that we're all always learning new things.

Comment: I try to always ask direct technical questions in forums if I can't find the answers right away. That way, they will get indexed by search engines so that next time myself and others can find the answers quickly. And pretending to know everything is disengenuous.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use [`.only()`](https://mochajs.org/#exclusive-tests). For example, your test file would look like this:

```
const { expect } = require("chai");

describe.only("contract tests", function () {
  it("does function one", async function () {
    expect(await someContract.someFunc()).to.equal(something);
  });
  it("does function two", async function () {
    expect(await someContract.someOtherFunction()).to.equal(somethingOtherThing);
  });
});
```

and then you can run `npx hardhat test` and it will only run that test set.

If you just want one `it`, instead of using `.only()` on `describe`, you can use `it.only()`.

EDIT:

As of hardhat version 2.9, you can use `--grep` as described in the original question.

Comment: This is great, but there is no command-line part I can run? I have to actually edit my code everytime I want to run just 1 test?

Comment: @PatrickCollins yes, because that's the way Mocha works. I'm not sure you can change the test runner with Hardhat, but if you can, note that with [Jest](https://jestjs.io/) and [Earl.js](https://earljs.dev/) you can run specific tests from the command-line.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the info all. Seems like this would be a nice improvement for mocha.

Comment: You can use Mocha's `--grep` to filter tests by their description. I personally think that adding `.only` is just easier, but YMMV.

Comment: Oh, and keep in mind that `npx hardhat test` doesn't support `--grep` (yet), so if you want to use it, you have to run mocha directly instead of using the test task.

Comment: When I use describe.only with hardhat the test runner finds nothing...

Comment: @Jim please create a question so you can include code and we can help further

Answer (score 13):

You'll be glad to know as of hardhat 2.9, the `--grep` parameter has been added to the [`test` task](https://github.com/NomicFoundation/hardhat/commit/368c8bfb5d7a23ff48a9105a60a445d3b5fb45eb)! This adds the ability to pass in a regular expression through to mocha! This is cool because you can

- Match a single part of the test. In your example Patrick, to run the first test:

  **`npx hardhat test --grep one`**

  would do the trick.
- Even cooler is matching different tests. If you wanted to test all matches for tests involving `add` and `convert`, the command:

  **`npx hardhat test --grep "add|con?vert"`**

  would match all the below tests in our "mock" test suite.

```
describe('Mocha', function () {
  describe('"grep" option', function () {
    it('should add a RegExp to the mocha.options object', function () {});
    it('should convert string to a RegExp', function () {});
  });
  describe('"fgrep" option', function () {
    it('should escape and convert string to a RegExp', function () {});
  });
  describe('.grep()', function () {
    it('should add a RegExp to the mocha.options object', function () {});
    it('should convert grep string to a RegExp', function () {});
    it('should covert grep regex-like string to a RegExp', function () {});
  });
});
```

Why the `?`? Well, it makes the `n` optional and I wanted to match one with a little [typo](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/ac43029d6a86150a48ccd59e50e89ca10c72a9c0/test/unit/grep.spec.js#L46).

Answer (score 3):

For anyone that finds this and is having a similar issue to me, `.only` or `fit`/`fdescribe` work great within a single file.

If you have multiple files you can do `hardhat test ./test/testfile.js`.

`.only` or `fit` won't work if you're running multiple test files at once.

Comment: when I run `hardhat test ./test/testfile.js` the output shows that it didn't find any tests in the file...

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna post since this is not the best option. You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/hardhat-watcher I then start it as a new package.json entry:

`"watch-test": "hardhat watch test",`

Comment: But you still need to use the `.only` yes?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If your tests are hardhat configuration specific, as specified in the CLI command, you could parse the CLI input directly in the test file. Then you could use Mocha's `.skip()` to ignore specific config based conditions.

I've applied this like the below example based off of network selections:

package.json

```json
{
  ...,
  "scripts": {
    "test": "hardhat test --network localhost",
    "test-hardhat": "hardhat test --network hardhat",
    "test-net": "hardhat test --network rinkeby"
  },
```

sample-test.js

```js
const { assert } = require('chai');

const PARMS = process.argv;
const NETWORK = PARMS[PARMS.indexOf('--network') + 1];

describe('ModifyVariable', function () {
    let contract;
    const inputStr = 'Applesauce';

    before(async () => {
        const ModifyVariable = await ethers.getContractFactory('ModifyVariable');
        contract = await ModifyVariable.deploy(10, inputStr);
        await contract.deployed();
    });

    // Maybe I'll run this. Maybe I won't...
    it('should change x to 1337', async function () {
        if (NETWORK === 'localhost') this.skip();

        await contract.modifyToLeet();
        const newX = await contract.x();
        assert.equal(newX.toNumber(), 1337);
    });

    // Always test rename to 'Bob'.
    it('should change publicString to "Bob"', async () => {
        await contract.modifyToBob();
        const newPublicString = await contract.publicString();
        assert.equal(newPublicString, 'Bob');
    });
});

describe('ModifyVariable', function () {
    let contract;
    const inputStr = 'Applesauce';

    // Maybe I'll run this. Maybe I won't...
    before(async function () {
        if (NETWORK === 'localhost') this.skip();

        const ModifyVariable = await ethers.getContractFactory('ModifyVariable');
        contract = await ModifyVariable.deploy(10, inputStr);
        await contract.deployed();
    });

    it(`should change publicString to "${inputStr}"`, async () => {
        await contract.modifyToInput(inputStr);
        const newPublicString = await contract.publicString();
        assert.equal(newPublicString, inputStr);
    })
});
```

output

```
$ npm run test

> hardhat-project1@1.0.0 test
> hardhat test --network localhost



  ModifyVariable
    - should change x to 1337
    √ should change publicString to "Bob" (2157ms)

  ModifyVariable
    - should change publicString to "Applesauce"


  1 passing (3s)
  2 pending
```